# How to get name of a class that is being extended

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have couple of grids that extend AbstractFormGrid. Having an object (that could be grid or not) how to check if this object extends AbstractFormGrid. I managed to get object class name using Ext.getName(object) or object.self.getName() but i am unable to get"parent" class.

Comment: Haha, of course -> Ext.getClass(object).superclass.self.getName(). Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The property `this.superclass` will return the parent class.

And as you mentioned this works:

```
Ext.getClass(object).superclass.self.getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

More straightforward approach is to use private property $className:

```
object.superclass.$className
```

Each class inherits this property from Ext.Base